# apending p into a div with an event listener

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm working on a small taskboard project and every time that I perform the `onclick` I get a `<p>` that has the vars in it (text, date and time) I have designed a div that has all the css styles applied to it. I am stup in the append child section that I can't get them to work together. my Goal is having the `<p>` on the "note".

```
function addTask() {
  var input = document.getElementById("toDo").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("dueByDate").value;
  var time = document.getElementById("dueByTime").value;

  var p = {};
  p.toDo = input;
  p.dueByDate = date;
  p.dueByTime = time;

  tasks.MyTask.push(p); // add object to array

  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tasks);

  localStorage.setItem("myList", JSON.stringify(tasks)) // save json to local storage;

  var div = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var myP = document.createElement("p");
  myDIV.appendChild(myP);
  document.getElementById("myDIV").appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Hi, which event you want to add to `p` tag ?

Comment: simple document.getElementById(elementthathasbeenclicked).onclick = addTask;

Comment: Hi, I would like to add an event listener to the add task in which the P is placed in "myDIV".